# Data Macros: Using default values if LookupRecord does not find a match

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-data-macro

I have been trying to set-up a Data Macro on one of the tables in Ms Access to add a 'path' and increment a level based on a parent record in the same table.

`Before Change`, if the parent node doesn't exist then default values are used. Otherwise, the parent's own path and level are looked up and the parent value of the current record is added on...  Well that's the theory.

[image: figure: BeforeChange Data Macro]

The first part of the `If` does in fact work, however, I can't get the `Else` condition to pull or populate the values into the current record.

Am I missing something or should this all be done `After Insert/Update`?

Comment: Perhaps something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dV8Mg.png)?

Comment: I see - so you look up the values inside the lookup block and assign to variables, then carry out the actual `SetField` on the outside of the block.  So am I right in thinking that operations on the inside of the `Lookup Record` block are primarily concerned with the fields from that lookup? (I'll just modify my trigger and see what happens)...

Comment: @GordThompson: Tried it and it works a treat. Please put this in as an answer and I'll credit it for you. Thank-you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Look Up A Record In ...` step creates a "block" of actions that will be taken if the lookup succeeds (and skipped if the lookup fails). It works like an `If ...` block in that respect.

So, we need to set the default values *before* the LookupRecord block, and use the resulting values (default or otherwise) in `SetField` actions *after* the LookupRecord block, like so:

[image: BeforeChange.png]

Comment: You've been a great help, Gord.  The trigger works perfectly now and forms the paths as required (eg: .0.1.4.5.) and increments the level.